# Resizing widget by dragging

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a custom widget. I would like to resize by dragging a corner of the widget. Currently, it automatically resizes when the cursor is near the corner of the widget

Here is the sample code. I would like to resize the widget by dragging the red triangle at the bottom right corner. Can I know how to do that?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QPointF, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QIcon, QColor, QPolygon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Stack(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Stack, self).__init__(parent)
        self._triangle = QPolygon()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.old_x_pos = 0
        self.old_y_pos = 0

    def _recalculate_triangle(self):
        p = QPoint(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 10)
        q = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 20)
        r = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 10)
        self._triangle = QPolygon([p, q, r])
        self.update()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._recalculate_triangle()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Stack, self).paintEvent(event)
        qp = QPainter(self)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)

        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        qp.drawRect(10, 10, 150, 150)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPolygon(self._triangle)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._triangle.containsPoint(
            event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill
        ):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        else:
            self.unsetCursor()
        
        super(Stack, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

            if event.x() > self.old_x_pos and event.y() > self.old_y_pos:
                self.resize(self.width() + (self.width() - event.x()), self.height() + (self.height() - event.y()))

            elif event.x() < self.old_x_pos and event.y() < self.old_y_pos:
                self.resize(self.width() - (self.width() - event.x()), self.height() - (self.height() - event.y()))

        else:
            self.unsetCursor()

        print(self.old_y_pos)
        self.old_x_pos = event.x()
        self.old_y_pos = event.y()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Stack()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have you though about using [QSizeGrip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizegrip.html)?

Comment: ok I just tried that now `self.gripper = QSizeGrip(self)

        layout.addWidget(self.gripper,0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)` but it resizes the whole window not the widget. Can u tell me how to use this properly?

Comment: You didn't specify that the widget was going to be added to a parent. And then I don't understand why don't you just follow and try to understand the answer on [your own question](Does this answer your question? [Resizing custom widget by dragging the edges in pyqt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64784966/resizing-custom-widget-by-dragging-the-edges-in-pyqt5)) (which makes this a duplicate). If there's something you cannot understand, please ask it there or clarify the specific need for a *new* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. For anyone else here is the modified code from the question. Using this code, you can resize the widget as well as move your custom widget around in the main window or the frame. To apply to your code you can simply copy-paste the code under `__init__()` and code under the mouse events.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPolygon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Stack(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Stack, self).__init__(parent)


        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self._triangle = QPolygon()
        self.start_pos = None

    def _recalculate_triangle(self):
        p = QPoint(self.width() - 20, self.height() - 10)
        q = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 20)
        r = QPoint(self.width() - 10, self.height() - 10)
        self._triangle = QPolygon([p, q, r])
        self.update()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self._recalculate_triangle()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(Stack, self).paintEvent(event)
        qp = QPainter(self)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)

        qp.setBrush(Qt.white)
        qp.drawRect(10, 10, 150, 150)

        qp.setPen(Qt.white)
        qp.setBrush(Qt.red)
        qp.drawPolygon(self._triangle)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.__mousePressPos = None
        self.__mouseMovePos = None
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._triangle.containsPoint(
                    event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill
            ):
                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
                self.start_pos = event.pos()

            else:
                self.__mousePressPos = event.globalPos()
                self.__mouseMovePos = event.globalPos()
                self.start_pos = None
                self.unsetCursor()

        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

        else:
            self.unsetCursor()

        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:

            if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton and self.start_pos is not None:

                self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)

                delta = event.pos() - self.start_pos

                self.resize(self.width() + delta.x(), self.height() + delta.y())
                self.start_pos = event.pos()

            elif not self._triangle.containsPoint(event.pos(), Qt.OddEvenFill):
                currPos = self.mapToGlobal(self.pos())
                globalPos = event.globalPos()
                diff = globalPos - self.__mouseMovePos
                newPos = self.mapFromGlobal(currPos + diff)

                self.move(newPos)
                self.__mouseMovePos = globalPos

                self.start_pos = None
                self.unsetCursor()

        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self.__mousePressPos is not None:
            moved = event.globalPos() - self.__mousePressPos
            if moved.manhattanLength() > 3:
                event.ignore()
                return

        self.start_pos = None
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Stack()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```